# Bash: compare 2 files and show the unique content of one file with 'hierachy'

Tags: bash, file, sorting, awk, comm

So basically, these are two files I need to compare

```
file1.txt
1 a
2 b
3 c
44 d

file2.txt
11 a
123 a
3 b
445 d
```

To show the unique lines in file 1, I use 'comm -23' command after 'sort -u' these 2 files. Additionally, I would like to make '11 a' '123 a' in file 2 become subsets of '1 a' in file 1, similarly, '445 d' is a subset of ' 44 d'. These subsets are considered the same as their superset. So the desired output is

```
2 b
3 c
```

I'm a beginner and my loop is way too slow... So here is my code

```
comm -23 <( awk {print $1,$2}' file1.txt | sort -u ) <( awk '{print $1,$2}' file2.txt | sort -u  ) >output.txt
array=($( awk -F ',' '{print $1}' file1.txt ))
for i in "${array[@]}";do
awk -v pattern="$i" 'match($0, "^" pattern)' output.txt > repeat.txt
done
comm -23 <( cat output.txt | sort -u ) <( cat repeat.txt | sort -u )
```

Anyone got any good ideas?

Another question: Any ways I could show the row numbers from original file at output? For example,

```
(row num from file 1)

   2                     2 b
   3                     3 c
```

Comment: Show us your current solution with a loop, we can improve on it.

Comment: Cool I've edited

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    vals[$2][$1]
    next
}
$2 in vals {
    for (i in vals[$2]) {
        if ( index(i,$1) == 1 ) {
            next
        }
    }
}
{ print FNR, $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
2 2 b
3 3 c
```